# Mock class to manipulate return value of function call in method

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test a class, every method is tested except for the last one, this one is kinda tricky for me because it calls another method in the same class and uses it's return value to return a string to the user.

```
/**
 * Get the total time elapsed as a
 * human readable string
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getElapsedTimeString()
{
    $elapsed = $this->getElapsedTime();

    return "{$elapsed} seconds elapsed.";
}
```

In order to test it i need to make sure that `$this->getElapsedTime()` will return a set value like 5 or 6, i've been trying to do this with mocks, but it's not working, it returns `null` every single time.

```
public function testGetElapsedTimeStringMethod()
{
    // Create Mock of the CarbonTimer class
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(CarbonTimer::class)
        ->getMock();

    // Configure the Mock Method
    $mock->method('getElapsedTime')
         ->willReturn(5);

    $this->assertEquals("5 seconds elapsed.", $mock->getElapsedTimeString());
}
```

What am i missing here? Sorry in advance if it's a dumb question, i'm just getting started with PHPUnit and it's a bit overwhelming

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like this, simply used setMethods with the name of the method i wanted to override, no idea why this worked yet, but it did.

```
public function testGetElapsedTimeStringMethod()
{
    // Create Mock of the CarbonTimer class
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder(CarbonTimer::class)
        ->setMethods(['getElapsedTime'])
        ->getMock();

    // Configure the Mock Method
    $stub->method('getElapsedTime')
         ->willReturn(5);

    $this->assertEquals("5 seconds elapsed.", $stub->getElapsedTimeString());
}
```